# Change header in bibliography - bibtex

Tags: bibtex, header-footer, report

In my latex document (`report`) I have an appendix made like this:

```
\appendix                             
\chapter{BLA BLA} 

\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thechapter. \:Statistiche UD Italian ISDT versione 2.6}]
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thepage}}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries}}

some text here
```

this formatting means that in the subsequent even pages, in the header of page, I have the page number on the left and the title of the appendix on the right. And this is correct. While in odd pages only the number appears on the right side of the title page and that's also correct.

Then I have the bibliography part made like this:

```
\bibliography{bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
```

the problem is that in this way, in the header of the even pages I always have the number on the left and the **name of the appendix on the right, instead of simply the word "bibliography"**.

How can I change the right part of the header page only for the bibliography part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Consult the documentation or a tutorial for the `fancyhdr` package. See e.g. [the Overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/headers_and_footers). You use the commands of the package in a peculiar way that messes up the header.
- Use the `babel` package with the option `italian`. This will set the title of the bibliography automatically (as well as other things for the Italian language).

Here is a sketch how to set up the header. If you cannot apply my suggestions to your setting, please post a *complete* document including the preamble. With the sparse information that you provide it is difficult to give adequate advice.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% use T1 font encoding for better glyphs
\usepackage[italian]{babel}% set up LaTeX for Italian
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clear header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}% page number on the left for even pages and on the right for odd pages.
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}% chapter title on the right side of even pages
\usepackage{lipsum}% only used for the sample text 
\begin{document}
\appendix                             
\chapter[Statistiche UD Italian ISDT]{Statistiche UD Italian ISDT versione 2.6}
% Note the use of the optional argument with a shortened title
% since the chapter title is too long to fit into a single header line

\lipsum[1-8]% generates sample text

\nocite{*}% includes all citations from bibliography.bib
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibliography} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you!